# JQuery not working in custom theme shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to tag my customer based on their email during registration. before this, the jQuery was working fine when it was added in the customers/register.liquid, even if I put in the theme.liquid in the 'Debut' theme. this is the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="customer_tags" name="customer[tags]"/>
        <script>
            jQuery('#{{ formId }}-email').on('input', function() {
         val = jQuery(this).val()
  if (val.indexOf('mycompany.com') !== -1) {
jQuery('#customer_tags').val('employee')
  } else {
  jQuery('#customer_tags').val('')
  }
          });</script>
```

However, when I select a different theme, putting the code wont be able to create autotag for me during registration. the thing is, for the new theme, the registration form is rendered together with login form in a page as follows:

```
{% section 'registration-form' %}
```

in registration-form, I have added the jquery, and match with the themes email id:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% form 'create_customer' %}
            {{ form.errors | default_errors }}

            <div id="first_name" class="clearfix large_form">
                <label for="first_name" class="login">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="customer[first_name]" id="first_name" class="large" size="30" />
            </div>

            <div id="last_name" class="clearfix large_form">
                <label for="last_name" class="login">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="customer[last_name]" id="last_name" class="large" size="30" />
            </div>

            <div id="email" class="clearfix large_form">
                <label for="email" class="login">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}</label>
                <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30" />
                <input type="hidden" id="customer_tags" name="customer[tags]"/>
                <script>
                    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('#email').on('input', function() {
                    val = jQuery(this).val()
                        if (val.indexOf('yspsah.com') !== -1) {

                          jQuery('#customer_tags').val('employee')
                    } else {

                        jQuery('#customer_tags').val('')
                     }
                })});</script>
            </div>
```

However this time, the autotag doesnt seem to work. even if I put the jquery on the theme.liquid, still cant solve the problem.
Anyone has any other idea that i should try to solve this? thank you!

Comment: As per my suggestion, you have to read customers/create webhook which returns JSON data of registered customers and in this, you set the tag to the customer as per your requirement. Refer this https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook
No need to update in any theme file.

Comment: what error you are getting in console ?